# Paver 0.8.1 compatibility with python 2.6

Tags: python, bootstrapper, build-environment

Does anyone manage to bootstrap its development area using paver with python 2.6 ?

I have install python 2.6, install paver with easy_install-2.6, everything looks fine.
But when I try to launch the bootstrap method it raises an urllib2.HTTPError (: HTTP Error 404: Not Found) while trying to download http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c8-py2.6.egg.
I have tryed to add the correct setuptools EGG file (which is 0.6c9) in the support-files directory, bootstrap.py find the EGG file, but doesn't seem to use it because it still try to download the 0.6c8 version which is no more available.

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Bertrand

Comment: This issue seems to have been addressed here:  http://groups.google.com/group/paver/browse_thread/thread/92a84f04c5bd1691

Answer (score 2):

You should try newer version. =) http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/